# How to access custom Wordpress database tables

Tags: wp-query, database, wpdb, table

I have this sample code that I found online that's supposed to count the number of rows in a table. Of course... It works, but when I created my own table using phpMyAdmin... It no longer works. What am i doing wrong?

I'm also wondering whey the "wp_users" table name dosen't work, but "users" does..

My table name is "test" I've also tried "wp_test" but for some reason none of them work.

```
<?php

$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users");
echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";

?>
```

FYI, I never use forums so forgive me if i'm not doing something right.

Comment: If you have table `test` your query will be `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test"`

Comment: Instead of ```$wpdb``` use WordPress Codex. User Count functions : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_users & https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_count

Comment: Re the users table question:  $wpdb->users  will insert the wp db prefix for you.  Makes code more portable so specifying wp_users would actually look for $wpdb->prefix.wp_users ie in your case wp_wp_users.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that's the table name? Usually on install WordPress prompts you to setup a table prefix so the default isn't `wp_`.

Additionally, you need to call the `global $wpdb` object so it's accessible to use:

```
global $wpdb;
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users" );
echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";
```

Finally, to prevent the prefix issue you can call `$wpdb->prefix`:

```
global $wpdb;
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users" );
```